# Change the default ToggleButton with MaterialDesignInXaml

Tags: xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have some big prominent color-coded `ToggleButtons` in my WPF app. I am trying out [MaterialDesignInXAML](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/home), however the toggle buttons default to very small switches. How can I use a larger toggle button?

You can see how the default looks here:

[image: Very small switch]

I'm using `TextBlocks` as button labels to accommodate word wrapping.

Each `ToggleButton` is like this:

`<ToggleButton Width="200" Height="200" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" 
              Name="Game0" 
              Foreground="{Binding Game0TextColor}"
              Background="{Binding Game0Color}">
        <!--Use TextBlock for word wrapping button text-->
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               TextAlignment="Center" 
               FontSize="22"
               Foreground="{Binding Game0TextColor}"
               Text="{Binding Game0Title}" />
</ToggleButton>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have pulled in the prescribed boilerplate, you can override a default style in a particular view as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- 
        Override style for ToggleButton to use because default is a small switch 
        Try also MaterialDesignFlatPrimaryToggleButton
        -->
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionToggleButton}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

[image]

See [Toggle Button examples on the wiki page](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Toggle-Button-Styles) and in the demo app.

Also have a look at the guide for [Overriding-Default-Styles](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Overriding-Default-Styles) if you want to change styles app-wide or factor it out.